# Why would this example give a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

Does anyone know why this would give me a segmentation fault?

cell.h

```
struct cell{
  bool filled;
  bool isParent;
  //float px,py,pz,s;
  bool cx,cy,cz;
  unsigned char r,g,b;
  vect norm;
  struct cell* parent;
  struct cell* child;

  cell(bool cxx=0, bool cyy=0, bool czz=0);

  void open_read(string);
};
```

cell.cpp

```
cell::cell(bool cxx, bool cyy, bool czz)
{
  cell childs[8];     // these lines creates a segmentation fault
  child = &childs[0]; // these lines creates a segmentation fault
  cx=cxx;
  cy=cyy;
  cz=czz;
  norm = vect(0,0,0);
  norm.normalize();
  isParent=false;
  filled=true;
}
```

If this is the wrong way to do this could anyone point me in the right direction as to how I could store a single pointer to the first element of child[8] instead of storing 8 pointers as it is quite memory intensive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to set up an infinite recursion. The constructor of `cell` allocates an array of 8 `cell` objects, whose construction in turn invokes the constructor of `cell` with default arguments.

Each stack frame consumes space, and sooner or later the stack will grow bigger than its size limit due to the non-terminated call recursion, eventually resulting in a segmentation fault.

Comment: It's not really infinite if it eventually stops...albeit in an ungraceful manner.

Comment: @SteveWellens: Right, what I meant is that he's trying to set up one. But you're correct. I edited my answer.

Comment: oh, i should have seen that, i guess i need to see how i could change my program so i dont need to invoke the constructor of the childs before actually needed.

Comment: @lasvig: Yes. You probably want to have only a collection of *pointers* to children (I suggest considering the use of *smart* pointers here), which may be stored after the construction of a cell object (or passed in as arguments, but not *created* during the creation of a cell, because that's again an attempt to set up infinite recursion).

Comment: i have had a array of pointers earlier, but what i am trying to do is to reduce child to a single pointer. so i dont need to use 64 bytes just to store 8 pointers.

Comment: @lasvig Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: How would std::vector use less memory?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a single `cell`, that `cell`'s constructor creates an array of 8 more `cell`s. Each of those creates an array of 8 `cell`s and so on and so forth. You have infinite recursion.

It is unclear why your constructor creates an array of 8 `cell`s - you only ever take the address of the first of them. It also doesn't make sense for each `cell` to automatically create its own child when it is constructed. That will lead to this infinite lineage of `cell`s.

Not to mention, at the end of your constructor, the array of `cells` will be destroyed and you'll be left with a pointer to an invalid object.